# regarding wpf dispatcher

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF and have a question regarding dispatcher and `Delegate.Invoke`.

In a windows forms application, we can use the invoke method to make changes to UI controls from other threads. This works because invoke *“executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle”* (as per msdn).

My question is:

1. Why doesn't `Invoke` work on WPF? It should be allowed to make changes to UI as the thread that owns the UI control gets to execute the delegate, but still it throws a runtime exception that *“a thread is trying to modify an object that is owned by a different thread”*.
2. How does the dispatcher manage to make changes to WPF controls while `Invoke` fails?
3. Is it possible to do cross thread programming in WPF without using dispatcher or background worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) why doesn’t invoke work on wpf?

It works fine, but perhaps you're not using it correctly. I suggest you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)

> It should be allowed to make changes to UI as the thread that owns the UI control gets to execute the delegate, but still it throws a runtime exception that “a thread is trying to modify an object that is owned by a different thread”

Perhaps you created a UI object on a worker thread, then tried to add it to the main UI on the UI thread ? Without seeing your code, it's only a guess...

> 2)How does despatcher manage to make changes to wpf controls while invoke fails?

This question is not very clear, but it's probably related to the first question anyway...

> 3) Is it possible to do cross thread programming in wpf without using despatcher or background worker?

If you need to manipulate the UI from a worker thread, you have to use the dispatcher. `BackgroundWorker` also uses the dispatcher (indirectly, through the `ISynchronizationContext` interface) to raise events on the UI thread. There's no way around it.